# ORA-00902: invalid datatype - column name contains hyphen

Tags: oracle

We have a table with the below structure:

```
CREATE TABLE XREF_WORKER_EMPLOYME_2(
    Siebel-01 VARCHAR2(2000),
    ROW_ID VARCHAR2(48) NOT NULL,
);
```

Table creation is failing with below error:

```
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

We need to keep the column named "Siebel-01".
Please suggest how to create table with this structure, also what further issues will come while inserting data or querying table with "-" in column name.

Comment: @downvoters: You should wait until minimum 5 minutes of waiting time on an answer or question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the name in double quotes.

```
CREATE TABLE XREF_WORKER_EMPLOYME_2( "Siebel-01" VARCHAR2(2000), ROW_ID VARCHAR2(48) NOT NULL );
```

But you will need to quote most queries against this column too.  Consider carefully if you really can't avoid this :)

Also, there is an extra comma at the end of the column definitions you need to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `comma` after the `NOT NULL` keyword, and there's a hyphen in one of the column names, which needs to be handled, if you want hyphern and not undesrcore

```
CREATE TABLE XREF_WORKER_EMPLOYME_2( Siebel-01 VARCHAR2(2000), ROW_ID VARCHAR2(48) NOT NULL, );
```

Remove that comma, to have your DDL like this

```
CREATE TABLE XREF_WORKER_EMPLOYME_2( Siebel_01 VARCHAR2(2000), ROW_ID VARCHAR2(48) NOT NULL );
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE XREF_WORKER_EMPLOYME_2( "Siebel-01" VARCHAR2(2000), ROW_ID VARCHAR2(48) NOT NULL );
```

Comment: If the -1 is for missing the hyphen, I have edited my answer. The other thing I highlighted in the answer was not something wrong, though it was just a part of the "issues"

Answer (score 0):

You have used **hyphen** instead of **Underscore** in Siebel-01  and Remove **Comma (,)** at the end..

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE XREF_WORKER_EMPLOYME_2(
    Siebel_01 VARCHAR2(2000),
    ROW_ID VARCHAR2(48) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that as Oracle does not permit (-) hyphen or minus sign into database name...

Please follow this link..
[Schema Object Naming Rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm)